# SAMSUNG S9 doesn't receive media button event when click Bluetooth headset play/pause button

Tags: android, button, media

Sorry that I can't attach our project code, so I will only describe my question.
I use the MediaSessionCompat.Callback to handle media button event in my app, when user click play/pause button of bluetooth headset, this call back will be invoked. I have tested on LG/SAMSUNG S7/Google Pixel 2, media session callback works fine. Only on SAMSUNG S9 will not call that callback. And if double click bluetooth headset button, will not dialing the last number either. 
Any solution to handle media button event for SAMSUNG S9, or this is a device issue? Any help will be grateful.